# gitignore config file for Github but not Heroku

Tags: git, heroku, github

Got an application that reads from a local `config.json` file. I have two remote repos - Github and Heroku. The Github repo is public but the contents of the config file are private - therefore I've added a `.gitignore` to prevent this file from being pushed.

However, when I push the app to Heroku I need the config file to be pushed so that the application can work - how do I deal with this situation?

**Note:** I'm reluctant to use Config vars as there are lots of settings in the config file.

Answer (score 1):

**Here you'll find out how to set options for heroku without commiting your config file.**

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

> Use the Heroku CLI’s config, config:set, config:get and config:unset
>   to manage your config vars

```
$ heroku config:set GITHUB_USERNAME=joesmith
Adding config vars and restarting myapp... done, v12
GITHUB_USERNAME: joesmith

$ heroku config
GITHUB_USERNAME: joesmith
OTHER_VAR:    production

$ heroku config:get GITHUB_USERNAME
joesmith

$ heroku config:unset GITHUB_USERNAME
Unsetting GITHUB_USERNAME and restarting myapp... done, v13
```

Remember that they have limits on the size of the config file.

If you have a lot of configurations perhaps you can create a **script** which automates the setting of configurations?

Comment: I don't want to use config vars - there are too many settings in the config file for this. I will update the question.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Blackwood Yeah that's true, don't know why I overlooked that. Edited.